# Getting a contentscript from browser.messageManager.loadFrameScript to listen for post message events

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

So I have my own xul interface containing a xul browser, and it needs to load a webpage from my website. Depending on the webpage, I'd like it to call window.postMessage, which my contentscript (loaded by loadFrameScript) should catch, and then subsequently talk back to the main script via sendSyncMessage.

The code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_message_manager works perfectly (Simple Example at the bottom) listening for click events from my webpage. However, I can't change the event listening type from "click" to "message". It just fails silently.

From the following:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.9/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html

I thought that maybe I was supposed to instead listen for messages from the webpage like so...

`document.defaultView.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  sendSyncMessage(...);}, false);`

... but when I try to set it up this way I get error messages saying that document doesn't exist.

Again, from the The_message_manager documentation, it lists the available globals for content scripts and I tried replacing "document" for "content"... to no avail.

Can anybody help? Thanx.

Comment: I see now that the references to the PageMod style of communication is completely separate to loadFrameScript. Not very familiar with Addon-SDK, but seems not applicable. Still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem with a twist.

Leaving no page unturned of Mozilla's documentation I stumbled apon this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages

It primarily suggests rather outmoded ways of sending off events (injecting elements) between the main webpage and chrome (not my use case).. but one of the lines is pure gold.

`"Note: If you're using HTML5's postMessage() to send a message from unprivileged code to privileged code, adding 'true' to the end of your event listener in your privileged chrome code will allow the message to be received.`

1
document.addEventListener("message", function(e) { yourFunction(e); }, false, true);"

Now this solution doesn't seem to work for window.postMessage() events, but the solution works perfectly for CustomEvents!! ...which also failed before adding 'true' as the mysterious 4th argument to addEventListener(). Custom Events fit my needs perfectly, so I consider this a solution.

So essentially I lost 2 days of my life due to this mysterious argument, which I blame fundamentally on the weakly typed nature and poor documentation of Javascript frameworks, as an IDE would have suggested this argument and presented it's documentation on use of the method.

However, thanx to stackoverflow, you won't have to :-)